# Starting a browser in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to run tests with selenium.  IE gives me a modal error after bringing up IE 8 with this text "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server" :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Ie() # Get local session of IE
browser.get("http://www.google.com") # Load page
time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

So I tried Chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

and Selenium errors for not having the right path to the chrome.exe application.  Chrome is installed as expected...            C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

A little help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have u downloaded the [Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)?

To get set up, first download the appropriate prebuilt server. Make sure the server can be located on your PATH or specify its location via the webdriver.chrome.driver system property.

Then when u run

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

It should work.

Comment: Hi @Amey, I put `webdriver.chrome.driver = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe'` into the script and have chromedriver.exe in that location.  Same error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure the server can be located on your PATH